# reduce garbage collection time in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, garbage-collection

**Garbage collection function in CI**

```
function _sess_gc()
{
    if ($this->sess_use_database != TRUE)
    {
        return;
    }

    srand(time());
    if ((rand() % 100) < $this->gc_probability)
    {
        $expire = $this->now - $this->sess_expiration;

        $this->CI->db->where("last_activity < {$expire}");
        $this->CI->db->delete($this-          ;

        log_message('debug', 'Session garbage collection performed.');
    }
}
```

Im new in codeigniter and i have found this GC function in codeigniter which in the Session.php libraries folder.

My problem is
how to change the time for the GC to delete expired session?

Example: I want it to delete expired session every 3mins..

But this function will delete expired session from database if the probability percentage is met..

Is there's a way of doing it?

Comment: Deleting expired sessions exactly every `3mins` needs a Cron job. What is the reason? Why do you care about this?

Comment: coz i got a problem in CI..to delete the session in DB..when the user just close the browser without using logout..Im storing the session in the database..:)..maybe GC to delete expired session every 3mins will do..:) but im just trying..anyway im new in CI..:)

Comment: You could `sess_expire_on_close` config item to `TRUE` to expire the user's session when the browser window is closed.

Comment: yeah..but when i enable to store session in database..it wont delete the records in the database  when i close the browser. @.@